# How can I protect the rsacryptoserviceprovider privatekey with a password and add it in windows store

Tags: c#, rsa, private-key, x509certificate2

I have a publickey certificate and a privatekey. Before adding to the x509store I want to protect the privatekey with a password.

My requirement is when I find the x509certificate2 from store using subject name I should get the certiifcate with the privatekey.But privatekey should be password protected without any ui prompt.

When creating rsacryptoservice provider I tried to attach key password to the csp params and I can able to create rsacryptoserviceprovider object.I have attached that to a x509certificate2 and added to the windows store. But after retrieving from store private key is throwing cryptographic exception.
[image]

```
var cspParams = new CspParameters
{
    ProviderType = 1,
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore
};

string passphrase = "password";
char[] passPhrase = passphrase.ToCharArray();
SecureString keyPassword = new SecureString();

for (int i = 0; i < passPhrase.Length; i++)
{
    keyPassword.AppendChar(passPhrase[i]);
}

cspParams.KeyPassword = keyPassword;
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
{
    rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
    rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
    X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoCertificate),
            "123",
            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
            X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet)
        {PrivateKey = rsaProvider};
        store.Add(x509Certificate);
}
```

Comment: And what error you get?

Comment: And is it only to me, but the code listing contains two duplicate code parts?

Comment: For PrivateKey field, CspKeyContainerInfo, KeySize and PublicOnly fields are throwing cryptographic exception.

Comment: Can you post full exception and stack trace?

Comment: '((System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey).CspKeyContainerInfo' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'

Comment: cspParams.KeyPassword is really meant for protecting the key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229231/discussion-between-anu-hardin-and-crypt32).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
{
    rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
    rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
    X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(<...>)
        {PrivateKey = rsaProvider};
        <..>
}
```

You are creating a new RSA asymmetric key pair and attempt to attach it to a certificate. However, this key pair is brand new and doesn't match the public key stored in certificate. Instead, you have to acquire private key handle from `X509Certificate2` object and work on it, do not create new keys, it will never work.

And do not use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` it is dead and obsolete. Instead, you must use `X509Certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()` extension method to get an instance of `RSA` class and extract CSP parameters from that `RSA` object.

Comment: If I have remove the keypassword property from CSPParameter it will work fine for me.var cspParams = new CspParameters
{
    ProviderType = 1,
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,KeyContername=  Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpperInvariant()
};  With this code i can able to attach privatekey to x509certificate and able to add it to the store.After adding to the store also I can able to read the privatekey.But I wanted to protect iprivatekey with a password.That is why I used KeyPassword.But unfortunately it is not working.